# Reference error: data is undefined next js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm a newbie in react. I used getStaticprops to fetch data from an api. I'm creating a filter gallery. Now when I tried to access the {props: data} outside the blog function it shows an error.
Reference Error: data is not defined.

Now how can I use data outside my blog function? I'll be very thankful if anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.[image: data undefined]

Comment: It's `undefined` because it's out of scope. Declare this variable in scope.

Comment: You can't access `data` variable outside `getStaticProps` or the `Blog` component, as it's scoped to those functions. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```js
let data = await getStaticProps();
const allSugg...
```

in blog function before return

Comment: Many many thanks for your reply. But where I need to add this code?

Comment: under const blog =